# import and use d3 in frontend

Tags: javascript, npm, d3.js, import

I know this might be a really silly question. But it would mean a lot to me to finally really grasp it!

So I simply want to include and use D3 (but could be any other npm-package) in the browser.

So I create a directory and an `index.html`. I start a new npm-project with `npm init -y`, I install the depencies `npm install d3`.  I create a file called `main.js` that looks like this:

```
// main.js
import * as d3 from "d3";
console.log(d3.scaleLinear());
```

where the index.html

```
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    this is the body
</body>

</html>
```

looks like this and the `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "HowDoesNpmWork",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^7.6.1"
  }
```

Yet I do get the error in the browser after running `npx serve`

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module main.js:1
```

I am not really getting my head around it. I am installing D3 and I'm saying it's a module in the package.json. What I am conceptually misunderstanding here? Can't I simply use any npm-package in the frontend?

And why does it work when I import D3 like this in the index.html ?

```
import * as d3 from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3@7";
```

Isn't it doing the same as loading it from `node_modules` ?

I'd

Answer (score 3):

You have to add that your code is a module

```
<script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
```

This still depends on D3 allowing direct import like this. Not all packages you install with `npm install` will work directly in the browser like this.

The other solution is to use a module bundler like [parcelJS](https://parceljs.org). This is the more traditional way to use `npm` in the front-end.

Comment: thanks a lot! With bundlers I get it:) But your first solution does not work for me :/

Comment: You have to realise that if you `import` a module without a bundler, the module should be available in the website's public folder. It won't work if you have a huge list of small `npm` modules in a `node_modules` folder. These will not all be automatically parsed and loaded by the browser. So it really depends on if D3 has support for direct loading as a ES6 module.